# unexpected token new, cannot find an answer

Tags: javascript, for-loop, token

I am trying to enter 2 numbers, the code will count from the start to the end number. I think im missing something, please look into this.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Count</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        1st number : <input type="number" id="start"> <br><br>
        2nd number : <input type="number" id="end"> <br><br>
        <button onclick="new()">Count !</button> <br><br>
        <p id="result"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function new()
               {
                for (start=0 ; start<=end ; start++)
                {
                    var start document.getElementById("start").value;
                    var end document.getElementById("end").value;
                    document.write(start+"<br>");
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=result;
                }
        }
```

Comment: Additionally to @pointy's answer: you are missing `=` signs in your variable declaration. Your loop will also never run, as `end` is `undefined` when the first comparison is done. `result` is never defined either...

Answer (score 5):

The word `new` is reserved in JavaScript and you can't use it as a function name.

Answer (score 2):

`New` is a reserved keyword. Use another variable name and it should be working.

Here is a list of reserved keywords: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words